# Add new row to time series DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a DataFrame loaded from a CSV file which I would like to append with a new row of values and then save it back to CSV. However, there are a few characteristics to this DataFrame:

- Its columns are not all of the same time, some are strings, some are floats (which makes [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe) not work for me;
- Its index is a datetime format which only needs to register the date, so whenever using `df.loc[datetime] = [value1, value2, .., value_n]` (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621712/add-a-new-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe-with-specific-index-name)), if the index already exists in my DataFrame, all rows containing the same date will be updated with the inputs;

One solution I managed to come up with was to create a new 1-row DataFrame from a dict using the original's columns as keys, so I could then apply `pd.concat` to add the new row, but I am wondering if there is a simpler and more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can append 1 row, with or without the index:

df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'value_1':value_1,'value_n':value_n},index=this_index))

df = df.append({'value_1':value_1,'value_n':value_n},ignore_index=True)

Comment: Using `ignore_index=True` resets it, though. If possible, I would like to keep the index as a datetime series.