# Add a new Row with specific Index Name at the Top of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame (`df1`) looking like this:

```
        0   
Height  175     
Weight  80
```

Now I want to add a row `Age` with the value `37` but not at the end (for this we have already a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621712/add-a-new-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe-with-specific-index-name)) but on Top of my DataFrame.

What I have yet tries is:

`pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df1.values, 0, values=['n',5], axis=0))` but I can onyl get this to work without the 'n' string and then there is only one column left.

Anyone a better idea that solves my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DataFrame` contructor with [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([37], index=['Age'], columns=[0]).append(df)
print (df)
          0
Age      37
Height  175
Weight   80
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([37], index=['Age'], columns=[0]), df])
```

Comment: perfect, this works for me. Thanks a lot and even with two possible ways.

Answer (score 1):

Because I can't comment, what do you want to do with the `values['n',5]` ?