# Pandas: How can I append a row to an existing dataframe that is indexed by date?

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, I would like to append a new row to an existing dataframe, using (my choice) the method at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16824696/1021819

Running `df.info()` on the existing dataframe gives:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 18 entries, 2011-10-03 00:00:00 to 2011-10-28 00:00:00
Data columns (total 1 column):
entry                   18 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
```

How can I append the row, in the case that - as here - the entries of the `Index` are not integers, but rather datetime objects, with the index created using

```
df.set_index('date')
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data from Jez, you mentioned `append` we can do it with `append`

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[0]},index=[pd.to_datetime('2018-05-16')])

df.append(df1)
Out[584]: 
                    A
2015-01-01  -0.828623
2015-01-02   0.060381
2015-01-03   1.202777
2015-01-04   0.676415
2015-01-05  -1.669687
2015-01-06   0.945452
2015-01-07  -0.045390
2015-01-08   1.926335
2015-01-09  10.000000
2018-05-16   0.000000
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for - thank you! But I feel bad choosing between your answer and that of @jezrael - what must I do? :-S

Comment: @jtlz2 I am ok with that , you can accept Jez' answer , and upvote mine maybe ? :-)

Comment: Hmm, well it was yours I actually used :\ Maybe they could be combined? I am going to upvote both now anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can change name of `Series`:

```
s.name = 10
```

to:

```
s.name = pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01')
```

Or more dynamic is add next day:

```
s.name = df.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')
```

Also is possible use [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement):

```
df.loc[df.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')] = s
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(145)

dates = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=8)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 1), columns=['A'], index=dates)
print (df)
                   A
2015-01-01 -0.828623
2015-01-02  0.060381
2015-01-03  1.202777
2015-01-04  0.676415
2015-01-05 -1.669687
2015-01-06  0.945452
2015-01-07 -0.045390
2015-01-08  1.926335

s = pd.Series([10], index=['A'])
s.name = df.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')
print (s)
A    10
Name: 2015-01-09 00:00:00, dtype: int64

df.loc[df.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')] = s
print (df)
                    A
2015-01-01  -0.828623
2015-01-02   0.060381
2015-01-03   1.202777
2015-01-04   0.676415
2015-01-05  -1.669687
2015-01-06   0.945452
2015-01-07  -0.045390
2015-01-08   1.926335
2015-01-09  10.000000
```

Comment: Thank you so much!