# How to add a new index row for an existent pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python Pandas 2D dataframe, where the column ITEM is the index.

```
ITEM   | A | B
ITEM-1 | 1 | 3
ITEM-2 | 1 | 2
ITEM-3 | 2 | 2
```

I have a process of creating a new column for a new jSON the script reads. If the items contained in this jSON response already exists in the dataframe, the value is assigned to the existent ITEM and the new column. Let's say I want to add value 3 to ITEM-1 to the new column C.

```
ITEM   | A | B | C
ITEM-1 | 1 | 3 | 1
ITEM-2 | 1 | 2 |
ITEM-3 | 2 | 2 |
```

But if the item does not exist in the dataframe, I need to create a new row for the dataframe and assign the value for this new row X column. Let's say I want to add value 2 to ITEM-4 (new item) to the new column C (HERE IS MY CHALLANGE).

```
ITEM   | A | B | C
ITEM-1 | 1 | 3 | 1
ITEM-2 | 1 | 2 |
ITEM-3 | 2 | 2 |
ITEM-4 |   |   | 1
```

This process is dynamic, reading a jSON response. I am trying to do this like sample below, but it's not correct.

```
#get information of resultID
url = '<URL INVOKED>'
respResult = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()

#add a new column to the dataframe
dataframe[respResult['name']] = ""

#get elements of the result
url = '<URL INVOKED>'
respElements = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()

#populate the dataframe with the elements and their values    

for element in respElements:

    #get the values of the element
    url = '<URL INVOKED'
    respElementValues = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()

    if(element['name'] in df.index):
        dataframe.loc[[element['name']],[respResult['name']]] = respElementValues['valueElement']
    else:
        #THIS BLOCK DOES NOT WORK
        dataframe.loc[len(dataframe)] = element['name'];
        dataframe.loc[[element['name']],[respResult['name']]] = respElementValues['valueElement'] #here the script returns the error "return_values_from_object(indexer) KeyError: ['ITEM-4'] not in index"
```

Comment: When you say "does not work", what are the details?  Is it generating an error (if so, consider adding the error to your question).  If it's working incorrectly, what's the result you're getting vs the result you're expecting?

Comment: @payne, this is the last part of the error: 
   1267                 if mask.any():
   1268                     raise KeyError('{mask} not in index'
-> 1269                                    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
   1270 
   1271                 return _values_from_object(indexer)

KeyError: "['ITEM-4'] not in index"

Comment: Suggest: adding that error (editing) to your question.

Comment: And, I think your question is a duplicate of this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824607/pandas-appending-a-row-to-a-dataframe-and-specify-its-index-label

Comment: @payne, that post does not answer exactly my question, because the approach there is different.

Comment: The post I sent a link to above should cover the "THIS BLOCK DOES NOT WORK" part of your code, above.  It shows how you *append* to an existing dataframe, with an index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dataframe.loc[element['name'],respResult['name']] = respElementValues['valueElement']
```

By removing `[]` from `element['name']`